# How to do routing with state in react next web application

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I created a react boiler plate app using `npx create-next-app@latest` as suggested in `[React official page](https://react.dev/learn/start-a-new-react-project) which is using react 18 and next js 14 version., I see folder structure as below.

```
├───public
└───src
    ├───app
        ├───page.tsx
```

react app landing page code is available page.tsx

I tried to create a next routing in react app to redirect to `/dashboard` page. But unfortunately., I see `404. This page is not found error

[image: error screenshot]

This is the folder structure I followed:

```
├───public
└───src
    ├───app
        ├───page.tsx
    ├───components
        ├───header.tsx
        ├───footer.tsx
    ├───images
    ├───pages
        ├───login.tsx
        ├───dashboard.tsx
        ├───not-found.tsx
    └───utils
```

This is my code in `page.tsx`

```js
import React from "react";
import { Container, Paper } from "@mui/material";
import LoginPage from "../pages/login"; 
import Image from "next/image";
import styles from "./page.module.css";

const LandingPage: React.FC = () => {
  return (
    <Container maxWidth="sm" style={{ padding: "20px" }}>
      <Paper elevation={3} style={{ padding: "20px" }}>
        <LoginPage />
      </Paper>
    </Container>
  );
};

export default LandingPage;
```

This is my code in `login.tsx`

```js
import React from "react";
import { Container, Paper, TextField, Button, Typography } from "@mui/material";
import MyLogo from "../images/MyLogo";
import { useRouter } from "next/navigation";

const LoginPage: React.FC = () => {
  const navigate = useRouter();
  const handleLoginClick = () => {
    const stateData = { message: "This is a dashboard message" };
    navigate.push("/dashboard");
  };
  return (
    <Container maxWidth="sm" style={{ padding: "20px" }}>
      <Paper
        elevation={3}
        style={{
          padding: "20px",
          display: "flex",
          flexDirection: "column",
          alignItems: "center",
        }}
      >
        <MyLogo />

        {/* Login Form */}
        <Typography variant="h5" gutterBottom>
          Login
        </Typography>
        <TextField label="Email" variant="outlined" fullWidth margin="normal" />
        <Button
          variant="contained"
          color="primary"
          fullWidth
          onClick={handleLoginClick}
        >
          Login
        </Button>
      </Paper>
    </Container>
  );
};

export default LoginPage;
```

This is my dashboard.tsx code:

```js
import { NextRouter, withRouter } from "next/router";
import React from "react";
import useAuth from "../utils/useAuth";

interface DashboardProps {}
const DashboardPage: React.FC<DashboardProps> = () => {

  return (
    <div>
        <h1>{'Welcome to Dashboard'}</h1>
      </div>
  );
};

export default DashboardPage;
```

This is my next.config.mjs code:

```js
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {};

export default nextConfig;
```

This flow is not working and getting 404 error when navigating to `dashboard` page.

My Requirements:

When I click on `login` button., it should navigate to `/dashboard` and pass state to `dashboard` page so that Dashboard can receive and process it.

I am new to next js., I used `react-router` earlier and next implementation seems different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Delete the `page.tsx` file in the `app` folder now that you have created a `pages` folder in the `src`.

Comment: ., do i need to delete `app` folder itself? I created `pages` folder inside `src` folder... default boiler plate code created `app` folder inside `src` folder and `page.tsx` available in `app` folder... when I deleted `page.tsx` file., landing page not loading.. So., i tried deleting `app` folder as well., so that nextjs would look for `pages` folder and pick its `index.tsx` and `page.tsx` file. still no luck. Now even landing page also not loading. Do i need to configure something in `next.config.mjs` ? I currently see `internal server error` after deleting `app` folder inside `src` folder...

Comment: Feel free to delete it

Comment: This works.. When I deleted `app` folder., next js started looking `index.tsx` inside `src/pages` folder and routing is happening to `/dashboard` and loading `dashboard.tsx...
But., when I do nested routing., like `/dashboard/details`., it is not loading `details.tsx` created under `src/pages`., do I need to create `/src/pages/details` folder and then create `details.tsx`... ? I tried that as well.. no luck.. getting 404 error in console..

Comment: Check this out: https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/routing/pages-and-layouts

Comment: Thanks... Understood flow now. Thanks